# Core Data - Sorting records that are fetched as part of relationship

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data

I have the following entities....

Person
 |
 --- Review

I retrieve a list of Person records .... and then I am directly able to reference the review records via Person.Reviews (which is nice and easy without having to write any NSFetch statements.)

My question is how do I sort the Reviews by date (there is a date attribute within the review entity) ? So that when I reference Person.Reviews they are in date order ?

My temp fix is to sort the array outside of the fetch

```
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"startDate" ascending:YES]];

NSArray *reviewList;
reviewList = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[person.reviews allObjects]] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean that you want to fetch the list of `Review` entities for a given person, sorted by date:

You can use `NSFetchRequest`, `NSPredicate` and `NSSortDescriptor` to do a filtered Core Data fetch with sorting of results.

Example:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = <#Get the context#>;

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Review"
    inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"person == %@", thePerson];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"startDate"
    ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSError *error;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
    // Handle the error.
}
```

The above code assumes your `Review` entity has a date field called `startDate` and a field called `person` which is a link back to the person.

After this code has run, `fetchedObjects` contains `Review` objects sorted into the review date order (and only reviews objects for the person of interest).

For more info, please read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/fetching.html

Comment: Thanks ... This looks great - Just have one question ... My person record has a relationship with the review entity and I want to retrieve the review records and sort by startDate in the review records... but yes I want to reference person.reviews but have the reviews in date order ... So I am not sure what to set the sort descriptor key to be? Can I put reviews.StartDate ?

Comment: @rs2000 Yes, that's correct. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: This caused an error ... "Exception = to-many key not allowed here" I've included my temporary fixed which is to sort outside of the fetch

Comment: Ah I see the problem, Person to Reviews is to-many. I've altered my answer. We also need an NSPredicate.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `NSFetchRequest` and `NSSortDescriptor` to sort your entity by date (ascending or not) :

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"YourEntityName" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entityDesc];

// Sort By date
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];    

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Comment: ?! I posted an answer first, get downvoted, someone else posts exactly the same answer after me, gets upvoted. Makes complete sense.

Comment: I downvote nobody @occulus. Isn't me sorry but thx for your downvote... However Stackoverflow is not a challenge of vote or whatever. When you answer, you didn't answer correctly because you explained how to sort depending x property and not for date. But, now you have edit your question so it's ok. Thx

Comment: I didn't accuse you of downvoting anyone.